# How to insert two arguments in list Python

Tags: python, list

I have

```
dollar_list = []

with open('fix/dollar.csv', 'r') as f:
    r = csv.DictReader(f)
    for dct in r:
        d = dct['date']
        # Convert '%d/%m/%Y' to '%Y-%m-%d'.
        d = datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        dollar_list.append(d, dct['value']) # <- here
    f.close()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

Comment: Use `extend()` to add more than one item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess maybe you want

```
dollar_list.extend([d, dct['value']]) # <- here
#list looks like [A1,A2,B1,B2,C1,C2,...]
```

or

```
dollar_list.append([d, dct['value']]) # <- here
#list looks like [[1,2],[3,4],..]
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not think extending is the right way, as an ordered pair of a date and a value shall be inserted into a list.

**Proposal** based on a tuple to represent the ordered (date, value) pairs:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import csv
import datetime as dt

dollar_list = []
with open('fix/dollar.csv', 'r') as f:
    for dct in csv.DictReader(f):
        dollar_list.append(
            (dt.datetime.strptime(
                dct['date'],  # Convert '%d/%m/%Y' to '%Y-%m-%d'.
                '%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
             dct['value'])
        )

print(dollar_list)
```

With `fix/dollar.csv`having:

```
date,value
31/01/2016,2.03
01/02/2016,2.02
```

Then running above script yields:

```
[('2016-01-31', '2.03'), ('2016-02-01', '2.02')]
```

**Notes**: I eliminated the close call (context manager does this), removed unneeded local variables. Esp. when overriding them again it may confuse the reader, because in the datetime transformation step of the questions formulation the `d` on the right hand side of the formular may easily be overlooked. Also you can directly iterate over an anonymous `csv.DictReader` instance. Last but not least added the required imports to make the sample complete.